# How to get just numerical value from a string in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have an xml file and i want to extract just the numerical value from a string in the file.One of the solution i came up with is

```
cat file.xml |grep -i "mu "| grep -o '[0-9]'
```

But i get each digit separated by new line,e.g for 100,i get 1 then new line,then 0 and so on.The other solution i came up with is

```
cat file.xml |grep -i "mu "|cut -d ' ' -f 4| tr '=' ' '|cut -d ' ' -f2|tr '""' ' '|sed -e 's/^ *//g' -e 's/ *$//g'
```

My question: Is there a simpler solution to this problem that i get just a numerical value from a line without caring about fields and not to use `cut` or `tr` commands?

Comment: Please provide an example of your string

Comment: `<mu value="100" />` But it can be different e.g there can be space between value and `=` sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this egrep:

```
egrep -o '[0-9]+'
```

Comment: Or in context `grep -i "mu" file.xml | grep -Eo '[0-9]+'`

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to delete everything that is not a digit from your input

```
tr -cd '[:digit:]'
```

Or for floating numbers

```
tr -cd '[:digit:].'
```

Comment: Thank you,it worked for me but not very comfortable with `[:digit:]`

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage avoidance of XML as a format, personally; at least for your own use.  Instead of "<mu value="100" />", you could use the following:-

```
# Name your data file ma-me-mo-mu.txt

100+200+300+400
```

and then:-

```
while IFS='+' read ma me mo mu
do
echo "${ma}"
echo "${me}"    
echo "${mo}"
echo "${mu}"
done
```

You don't need to name your columns inside the data file itself.  They go in the file name.